# Unable to create a contribution from back-office (Civi 5.21.2)

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

Configuration:
- Civi 5.21.2
- Wordpress

What am I trying to do : Create a contribution manualy trhough the back-office :http://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Fadd&reset=1&action=add&context=standalone

here is my filled form:
[image]

When submitting the form I get this error:

```
CRM_Core_Exception: One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php on line 1524
```

Exception trace:

```
#   Function    Location
0   CRM_Utils_Type::validate('', 'Integer') /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1524
1   CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery('SELECT id,name,l…', Array, true)    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1402
2   CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('SELECT id,name,l…', Array)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceSet.php:475
3   CRM_Price_BAO_PriceSet::getSetDetail(null)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution.php:1371
4   CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution->submit(Array, 1, null)    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution.php:944
5   CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution->postProcess() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:479
6   CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:153
7   CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution), 'upload')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:120
8   CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution), 'upload')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
9   HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution), 'upload')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
10  HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle('upload')   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:335
11  CRM_Core_Controller->run()  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Page/Tab.php:316
12  CRM_Contribute_Page_Tab->edit() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Page/Tab.php:372
13  CRM_Contribute_Page_Tab->run(Array, null)   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:268
14  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:68
15  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
16  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1449
17  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')   /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:288
18  WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)   /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:312
19  WP_Hook->do_action(Array)   /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php:478
20  do_action('toplevel_page_Ci…')  /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php:254
21  {main}
```

I'm sure this issue is due to some misconfiguration of some kind.
Could someone help with that?
What Am I missing.

I also have a 500 error when viewing an existing contribution.

Any help appreciated, we are stuck in this situation.

Comment: This sounds familiar and may be related to Financial Account translations. Administer > Contribute > Financial Accounts (comptes financiers). Can you check, for example, if "Accounts Receivable" exists?

Comment: Hello @bgm

It seems ok : https://ibb.co/5cHgxGd

I saved each account again just to be sure...

I don't get what civi expect from this line of code : 
      $this->_priceSetId = $priceSetId = CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue('CRM_Price_DAO_PriceSet', 'default_contribution_amount', 'id', 'name');

The priceset retruned is Null, and makes the code fails afterwards.

Comment: Can you try renaming "Comptes à recevoir" to "Accounts Receivable"?

The getFieldValue() does the equivalent of `select * from civicrm_price_set where name = 'default_contribution_amount'` (I think)

Comment: Ok, so I found out why (thx to bgm)

The quick configs where not in db.
I compared a "clean" new install and inserted the default price set.

Resolved. Thanx @bgm

Comment: @bgm if you post an answer folks will upvote it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the trace and to your comments, this SQL query can help find if there is data missing from the database:

```
SELECT * FROM civicrm_price_set WHERE name = 'default_contribution_amount'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do have have any overridden / customised files?

I came across similar issues recently but was ultimately down to customisation.

Would suggest trying with core version of those files and see if it works correctly for you :).

Comment: Not on civicontribute :-(